# Как изменять значения в Input в зависимости от значений в других Input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Делаю конвертер валют по курсу Нацбанка Беларуси. Получилось конвертировать, когда ввожу BYN. Но другие валюты по итогу просто нельзя поменять. [Вот как](http://www.myfin.today/converter) это реализовано на фронте. Если вы загрузили страницу и курсы не появились, то перезагрузите ещё раз (я пока не понял почему так, разбираюсь с другим). Когда загрузятся курсы, тогда можете менять значения в поле BYN - всё считает нормально. А после этого - не могу ввести никаких данных в другие поля.

Вот код:

```
$('#nbrbBYNInput, #nbrbUSDInput, #nbrbEURInput, #nbrbPLNInput, #nbrbUAHInput, #nbrbRUBInput').on('input', function () {

let BYNValue = +document.getElementById('nbrbBYNInput').value;
let USDValue = +document.getElementById('nbrbUSDInput').value;
let EURValue = +document.getElementById('nbrbEURInput').value;
let PLNValue = +document.getElementById('nbrbPLNInput').value;
let UAHValue = +document.getElementById('nbrbUAHInput').value;
let RUBValue = +document.getElementById('nbrbRUBInput').value;

let USDSum = 0;
let EURSum = 0;
let BYNSum = 0
let PLNSum = 0;
let UAHSum = 0;
let RUBSum = 0;

EURSum = BYNValue / eurTodayRate;
USDSum = BYNValue / usdTodayRate;
PLNSum = BYNValue / plnTodayRate;
UAHSum = BYNValue / uahTodayRate;
RUBSum = BYNValue / rubTodayRate;



document.getElementById('nbrbEURInput').value = EURSum.toFixed(4);
document.getElementById('nbrbUSDInput').value = USDSum.toFixed(4);
document.getElementById('nbrbPLNInput').value = PLNSum.toFixed(4);
document.getElementById('nbrbUAHInput').value = UAHSum.toFixed(4);
document.getElementById('nbrbRUBInput').value = RUBSum.toFixed(4);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю насколько по канонам js, но в итоге я просто разделил oninput. Вот так получилось для ввода BYN:

```
$('#nbrbBYNInput').on('input', function (){
let BYNValue = +document.getElementById('nbrbBYNInput').value;


EURSum = BYNValue / eurTodayRate;
USDSum = BYNValue / usdTodayRate;
PLNSum = BYNValue / plnTodayRate;
UAHSum = BYNValue / uahTodayRate;
RUBSum = BYNValue / rubTodayRate;


document.getElementById('nbrbEURInput').value = EURSum.toFixed(4);
document.getElementById('nbrbUSDInput').value = USDSum.toFixed(4);
document.getElementById('nbrbPLNInput').value = PLNSum.toFixed(4);
document.getElementById('nbrbUAHInput').value = UAHSum.toFixed(4);
document.getElementById('nbrbRUBInput').value = RUBSum.toFixed(4);

});
```

Вот так для ввода USD:

```
$('#nbrbUSDInput').on('input', function () {

let USDValue = +document.getElementById('nbrbUSDInput').value;

BYNSum = USDValue * usdTodayRate;
EURSum = BYNSum / eurTodayRate;
PLNSum = BYNSum / plnTodayRate;
UAHSum = BYNSum / uahTodayRate;
RUBSum = BYNSum / rubTodayRate;




document.getElementById('nbrbEURInput').value = EURSum.toFixed(4);
document.getElementById('nbrbPLNInput').value = PLNSum.toFixed(4);
document.getElementById('nbrbUAHInput').value = UAHSum.toFixed(4);
document.getElementById('nbrbRUBInput').value = RUBSum.toFixed(4);
document.getElementById('nbrbBYNInput').value = BYNSum.toFixed(4);
});
```

Для последующих валют точно также.
Буду рад, если подскажите как сократить код и сделать лучше.